# datagriview get the cell by row name and column name

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I created a datagridview and I would like to update some data in cell value .
I know how to it when we clic on the cell but I am looking by another way .

```
userlist |1 july 2| july 3 |july 4

Martin
Lukas
franck

I found $datagridviewResults.Columns["july 3"].Index and now I need the same think for the row .
```

exemple I want to add 10Pm to 12PM for Martin and the date will be 3 july

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some workaround

```
    $colunmIndex=$datagridviewResults.Columns["july 3"].Index #I got the column index
    $find = $textboxtest.Text
        $rowcount=$datagridviewResults.RowCount
        $rowindex=-1 # I put -1 because index++ will add +1 and start at 0
        Do
        {
        $rowindex++
        $Rowname= $datagridviewResults[$colunmIndex,$rowindex].value
        }until(($Rowname -like "$find") -or ($rowindex -gt $rowcount))
    #we have both index so now we can edit

    $datagridviewResults[1, $rowindex].Value = 'nice'

#Also if the script can't find the row index , the value at the end will be null .
```

Still if you have a better solution ,I am interested .